# Any way to view contents of init files

Tags: 18.04, executable

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I have a file called init and it is an executable (appplication/x-executable). I would like to read the content of the executable. When I use the cat command, I see gibberish. 
When I used the file command, it returned

> init: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, ...

Is there any way for me to view the contents?

Comment: I would suggest `hexdump -C init`  (-C displays hex & ascii), but I'm not sure if this will help you as you may be hoping for a decompile, which is more than this produces

Comment: `TERM=vt100 && export TERM`? also `pstack` could potentially work instead of cat

Answer (score 0):

This is a binary (compiled and linked executable) file. If you want to extract the strings in the executable code (e.g., messages, initialized variables etc.) You can use:

```
strings init | less
```

For more information look at:

```
man strings
```